# Calculate 4point the closest from the User'position ? (Android)

Tags: java, android, math

I'm working on a geolocalisation project. And I want to determine which are the 4points the closest from my position. As you can see on the picture below :

[image]

Arrow red : Position of the USER (I can get easily his position on the screen)

Blue Point : All the point where I need to determine which are the 4 the more closer from the User.

Here, it would be the ones surounded in red. I also can get their position easily on the screen. I just need the math's equation to know the 4 points concerned.

Thank's for ur precious help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved :

I first of all calculate the distance using the basic equation for each points :

`sqrt((Xb-Xa)² + (Yb-Ya)²)`

then I sort the result of each points (ascending) :

```
Object[] a = distance.entrySet().toArray();
        Arrays.sort(a, new Comparator() {
            public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
                return ((Map.Entry<Integer, Double>) o1).getValue()
                        .compareTo(((Map.Entry<Integer, Double>) o2).getValue());
            }
        });
```

And just did a for with the first 4 to got my 4 closest point. ez pz :) !